# How to create grooves with texture

Tags: texturing, normal-map, procedural

I am an avid software engineer, but new to Blender. I am trying to create an ammo clip for a video game. It is inspired by the Mass Effect "Thermal Clip", and I have a reference fan image I'm using for some baselines.

I have the basic geometry finished, but I am unsure about how to create the techno-looking grooves which outline the red bars and other edges. I would like to use a texture normal map instead of adding more geometry, but any reference to how to make that look would be great.

I am a very new to blender, so even keywords to google would be helpful.

[image: Simple Geometry of my ammo clip. Pretty plain.]

[image: Reference image. Please observe the red dashes, and the grey grooves.]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't ask more than one question per post. Use the [edit] below, to break this into multiple posts so that each focuses on a single issue. Make as many separate questions as necessary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create geometry/ textures for procedural shading?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/277453/how-do-i-create-geometry-textures-for-procedural-shading)

Comment: @Chris, I am referencing the dark grey outlines/ grooves slightly indenting the sides, head, and feet of the example model. Are geometry nodes the best way to go about that?

Comment: @MadboyJames, Geo Nodes are probably the best way to go, but if this is going to unity you need to use probably a mesh that is altered. Maybe use displacement textures?