# How do I create geometry/ textures for procedural shading?

Tags: texturing, normal-map

I am an avid software engineer, but new to Blender. I am trying to create an ammo clip for a video game. It is inspired by the Mass Effect "Thermal Clip", and I have a reference fan image I'm using for some baselines.

How would I create the red bars? I think using a texture would be better than adding geometry, but I am unsure. Additionally, I would like to procedurally shade the red bars in a "progress bar" fashion, which may mean I need to create them in a specific way.

I am a very new to blender, so even keywords to google would be helpful.

[image: Simple Geometry of my ammo clip. Pretty plain.]

[image: Reference image. Please observe the red dashes, and the grey grooves.]

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE  - shader nodes solution with custom attributes to "hopefully" work in UNITY:

1. Create a plane (or whatever shape you want)

open custom attributes here:

[image]

press new

change to integer and max 100 like this:

[image]

2. then press SHIFT-D y 3 -> this duplicates your plane
3. then hit SHIFT-R a few times, then you got:

[image]

4. press "Shading" tab, press "new" to create new material

[image]

5. use these nodes:

[image]

6. in the value node is a so called "driver". Just write an "#frame" into it. This will spit out the frame for each frame.
7. change the custom property of each plane to 0 for the first plane ,1 to the second plane,2 to third,3 ...and so on

result:

[image]

[image]

---

sorry, first i have to apologize, this is not really an answer for a Blender beginner...

but maybe it motivates you to learn geometry nodes ;)

Geometry nodes are pretty new to Blender and still under development and the Blender developers made great progress in this. It is already very powerful.

So i try to explain it for beginners.

1. add a plane. SHIFT-A -> Mesh -> plane. Plane

[image]

2. click on modifiers tab

[image]

3. add geometry nodes modifier

[image]

4. click on new
5. build this node tree setup:

[image]

6. press on material properties -> click "new"

[image]

7. add this node setup:

[image]

8. in the geometry nodes modifier enter "strength" in value

[image]

9. make sure that the node "set material" is the material you created in point 6

[image]

10. result:

[image]

you can now change the geometry (your plane) however you like, it will work.

[image]

result:

[image]

Geometry nodes explanation:

The mesh line does create 10 vertices, with an y offset of 2.
The instance on points create 10 instances (one on each vertex) on these vertices with the object, you plug in "instance", which is the plane here. The capture attribute save the index of each instance for later use.
Set material is self explanatory.
Scene time spits out the frame. I multiply this with .3 so that the animation gets slower.
Then i compare the (slowed down) frame with the index of the instances (which goes from 0 to 9). If that frame is greater than the index, i save this value for later use (that's what the 2nd capture attribute does with its connection to the group output).
By entering the value name in the geometry nodes modifier

[image]

i can then use that attribute in the shaders editor:

[image]

so i use this value (fac) to drive the strength of my emission of my planes.

Comment: ...this is one of the rare cases where you don't use miles of links between nodes, and where you really made an effort to write the answer understandably. Are you on vacation right now? ;-)

Comment: He said he is a beginner. ‍♂️ if they don’t write it, I assume they are pros and don’t need explanation 

Comment: Elegant, considerate!  I couldn't possibly comment on @quellenform s remarks.... ,,, ...Hope it's sunny, wherever you are :D

Comment: @Chris, Thank you for the explanation! That helps a lot. I have one question, since this model will be used in Unity: Since the geometry generated by the nodes will need to be made "real" before importing to Unity, will the material still work like a "progress-bar" in Blender even if the geometry is no longer procedural? 

(If there is a fundamental issue with my question/ understanding, such as "we can't make procedural geometry real" or something, please let me know).

Comment: @MadboyJames: I have nearly no knowledge about Unity and i think i haven't read your question carefully. I think Unity doesn't support GN and so my solution is pretty worthless if you want to use it there...sorry. And if you apply the GN modifier, you won't have the attribute value which you would need to animate it correctly.

Comment: does unity support custom attributes and this shader node [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgoNr.png ? then i can offer you a solution

Comment: Unity does support custom attributes, and I think it has the elements to make that shader node from other nodes. https://i.imgur.com/euxpXA3.png

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! When I have results, I'll update my post.

Comment: @MadboyJames if my answer helped you, pls click on the checkmark left of my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From your other posts I assume you want to use the model in Unity. This means geometry nodes are out. This is a node setup you can fairly easily convert manually to Unity's shader forge:
[image]
I used a quick wave texture to get the stripes, ultimately you're probably best off creating an image texture for that (and skipping the color ramp)
If you unwrap your model, you can use UV instead of generated, Unity doesn't have the generated coordinates.
The less than threshold (green) is the progress of the red lines.
Essentially use a texture that is black and white replace the white parts with a color, the distance from 0 (whatever you choose it to be, use UV if possible) will determine whether to fill in red or leave it at its original color.