# How do I create a procedural "fill-up"/ "Progress-Bar" shader?

Tags: shaders

I am an avid software engineer, but new to Blender. I am trying to create an ammo clip for a video game. It is inspired by the Mass Effect "Thermal Clip", and I have a reference fan image I'm using for some baselines.

How would I create a "progress bar" shader for the red bars, where I can set something like 10% and 1 bar lights up (assuming there are 10 bars. The image has 12... so in that case if I set 8.3% one bar lights up). Any references would be great.

I am a very new to blender, so even keywords to google would be helpful.

I asked two questions before this one. Reviewing them may give some context.

[How to create grooves with texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/277446/how-to-create-grooves-with-texture)

[How do I create geometry/ textures for procedural shading?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/277453/how-do-i-create-geometry-textures-for-procedural-shading)

[image: Simple Geometry of my ammo clip. Pretty plain.]

[image: Reference image. Please observe the red dashes, and the grey grooves.]

Comment: Making a material in Blender is not going to be the same as making your material in your video game engine.  Are you sure you don't want to be asking somewhere focused on your game engine instead?

Comment: @Nathan, I'll definitely need to figure out how to convert a Blender material into a Unity material, but first I need to figure out how to make this effect in Blender. Then, if no conversion exists, I will make the material in Unity.

Comment: @Chris, Yes! Yes it does. :)

Comment: You won't do yourself any favor if you get it right in Blender, only to never use it in Blender. Converting materials is all but trivial and in a simple case like this I would just do it (twice) manually. Or is your idea trouble-shooting in Blender and then transforming that to the Unity Shader Nodes?